# How to get Request payload content at Response path class mediator using OMElement - WSO2 APIM ver 3.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 APIM version 3.2.0.

I have a POST request with the request payload.
In the response message mediation of WSO2 APIM I have added the policy that contains the class mediator that tries to get the payload sent during the request.

OMElement element = (OMElement) mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstOMChild();
log.info("payload: " + element.toString());

The above code snippet prints the response payload content but I need the request payload content at the response path.

[Response message mediation with a policy added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afr9H.png)

Below is the sequence with class mediator

[sequence with class mediator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuV6Z.png)

Code snippet inside class mediator

OMElement element = (OMElement) mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstOMChild();
log.info("payload: " + element.toString());

Pls let me know what changes to be done, to get the request payload content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have to store the request payload in a custom property in the Message Context. Then, we can use that property to retrieve the Request Payload in the Response path of the execution.

For example: You are invoking an API with JSON Payload. So, we have to first capture the sent payload and store it in a custom property in the Message Context. Given below is a sample sequence to perform the same

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="admin--MockAPI:v1.0.0--In">
   <property name="RequestPayload" expression="json-eval($)" />
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="RequestPayload" expression="$ctx:RequestPayload" />
   </log>
</sequence>
```

Then, in the Response path, inside your custom class mediator, you have to access the `RequestPayload` property from the `MessageContext` to extract the stored payload. You can achieve this by using the following snippet

```java
synapseContext.getProperty("RequestPayload");
```